# loading scriptreferences dynamically with aspx Usercontrols and telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, scriptmanager

I'm making a project with Telerik Radcontrols based on the demo at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/multipage/dynamic-pageview-creation/defaultcs.aspx, which involves dynamically loaded pageviews with usercontrols in them. This worked just fine at first, but I've had to temporarily revert to statically loaded controls because my asp:scriptreferences to javascript files would not load alongside the dynamic controls. I've googled this and http://forums.asp.net/t/1491236.aspx?How+to+create+a+flipcart+like+panel+for+showing+products+in+gridview appears to say that it's a bug in the ScriptManagerProxy, which isn't able to register itself correctly if it's dynamically loaded.

I really want to get this dynamic loading to work because it would make the application load much faster. Currently, it takes 12 seconds to load main.aspx on my development machine, compared to 2-3 seconds seconds when they were dynamically loaded. This is of course unacceptable.

I've tried adding the scriptreference dynamically through the code-behind, using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398991(v=vs.100).aspx, but that also doesn't work, because the javascript isn't loaded.

What alternatives are there to the asp:Scriptmanagerproxy and asp:scriptreference combination?

Comment: Why would you need the proxy? The controls will find the global instnace of the script manager and use that to register the scripts they need. You do not need to manually add their scripts as script references.

Comment: You mean you can just add scriptreferences ahywhere in the page without a proxy or a manager?

Comment: no, I mean that I am not aware of any explicit need to have a ScriptManagerProxy and registering Telerik scripts in it at all. The controls should handle that themselves just fine. Not proxies or script references needed.

Comment: I'm not talking about the telerik javascript files. I have custom javascript client-side validation code which I want to load dynamically when the relevant usercontrol is loaded. For example, Usercontrol A is loaded at the same time as the page with custom JS A1 and A2. I have a usercontrol B which I load dynamically when a button is pressed. that also needs to load custom JS file B1. When I try to add a scriptmanagerproxy on B with scriptreferences to B1, it does not load those properly. the scriptreferences on A to A1 and A2 load properly.

Comment: Try adding the script references to the main script manager programmatically. See the ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page) method

Comment: I've tried that as well on the page_load() method. It still doesn't load the scriptreferences.

Comment: then this must be something between user controls, script manager and scriptManagerProxy. If you have URLs to the needed scripts you can consider using the RegisterClientScriptInclude method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptinclude(v=vs.110).aspx
to add the script to your page. If it is in an assembly, look into the GetWebResourceUrl Method to get the URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just considered something. Can I maybe just use regular script tags?

Comment: I've tried a regular script tag, it doesn't work either. For now, since it's a really small script, i've added it to my default scripts to load. I'm not that happy with this solution, but it works for now.